# Is possible to connect to Kafka with Robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I want to connect and test Kafka.
Is it possible to test using RobotFramework. 
Any exist library for this.

Thanks
Sarada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this post is 5 years old, but the answer (at least now) is **yes**!

- [Repository](https://github.com/robooo/robotframework-ConfluentKafkaLibrary)
- [Keyword documentation](https://robooo.github.io/robotframework-ConfluentKafkaLibrary/)

Sorry I don't have enough experience to provide any tutoring on it (I'm a newb with Kafka), but at least it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to interact with and thus test kafka with RobotFramework. Highly unlikely there exists a library for it however, based on a brief web search.

See my earlier response to this old thread that gives a detailed discussion of what you're asking about and how to go about solving it, minus the actual implementation (which is a significant amount of work, hence no one has written and shared such a library yet).

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotframework-users/gnfR12xAU4U

Comment: Thanks for your reply David, let me give a try

Answer (score 0):

YES ! there is an existing library to support Kafka automation

> pip install robotframework-confluentkafkalibrary